# In CakePHP, what is the difference between $_SESSION['Auth'] and Authentication->getIdentity()?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-4.x

Titlte says it all I think.

I have encountered both and don't know which one I should use between $_SESSION['Auth'] and $this->Authentication->getIdentity(). Is one safer than the other ?

Thank you,

Simon

Answer (score 0):

With CakePHP you should always use the abstracted APIs to access any superglobal data like `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, `$_SESSION`, etc..

This is advised for a multitude of reasons that depend on the specific situation, but generally it kinda touches the principle of dependency inversion, and decoupling in general, eg. your code should depend on abstractions, not concretes, then for example implementations can change without breaking your application. And while the session object, the request object, or the authentication component aren't interfaces, they still abstract the access to the underlying data (the concrete so to speak).

Something where the need for this would apply generally, would be testing, except for the CakePHP session object, which *must* write the data to the `$_SESSION` superglobal internally, other superglobals like `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, etc. are not being populated if you use the API provided by CakePHP, instead the data is written into the request object, which exposes the data via its own API. So if you were for example to access `$_POST` directly in your code, and then pass POST data in a test like `$this->post('/url', $postData)`, your code wouldn't see the data, as it would directly land in the request object instead of the `$_POST` superglobal.

As far as the authentication example specifically goes, the authentication middleware could have obtained the identity with data from who knows where, the session, cookies, tokens, etc., and likewise it could persist the identity anywhere, the session, cookies, etc, the inner layers of your application shouldn't have to care about such implementation details, they obtain the identity via the component, or from the request object, and that's it, they don't need to know anything else, then you can easily change how authentication is handled without breaking the rest of your application.